In finite element method for second order elliptic problem with neumann boundary value, is the solution weakly satisfies the boundary conditions?
For example, let's consider the problem
\begin{equation}
-\Delta u+u = 0
\end{equation}
For $g\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}((D)$, where $D$ is the domain, assume that $u$ is the solution of
\begin{equation}
(u,v)_{H^1(D)} = 0,\forall v\in H^1_0(D)
\end{equation}
with $u = g$ on $\partial D$. Is $u$ also the solution for find $w\in H^1(D)$ such that
\begin{equation}
(w,v)_{H^1(D)} = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial n},v)
\end{equation}
can you give some hint or idea to prove this?

Since from strong solution view-point, it seems reasonable.

You would need extra assumptions on the domain and the boundary data $g$. In particular if $g$ is the trace of a function that does not belong to $H^2$, then $u$ will not be regular enough to be a strong solution satisfying $-\Delta u + u = 0$ a.e.
Similarly if the domain is irregular, e.g. not $C^2$, or non convex, the same can be said.
